# Cannot get data out from redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I can see all the data I want in the redux state from the website extensions, however, when I want to pull it out to use it in my component it said this.props.rules is undefined:

Here is the create-store.js:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import mainReducer from './reducers/main-reducer';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default () => {
  return createStore(mainReducer, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  ))
}
```

Here is the mainReducer.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

import rules from './rules-reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  rules
});
```

Here is the rules reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  allRules: [],
  singleRule: {}
}

export default (state = {}, {type, payload}) => {
  switch(type){
    case 'GET_RULES':
      console.log('got in get_rules reducer');
      return {
        ...state,
        allRules: payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
      }

};
```

Here is the getRulesAction:

```
export const getRulesAction = () => dispatch => {
  console.log('got into getrulesaction');
  const sheets = Object.entries(document.styleSheets);
  let allRules = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    const sheet = sheets[i][1];
    const rules = Object.entries(sheet.cssRules);
    for(let j = 0; j < rules.length; j++){
      // console.log(rules[j][1].cssText);
      allRules.push(rules[j][1].cssText);
    }  
  }
  dispatch({
    type: 'GET_RULES',
    payload: allRules
  })
  
};
```

Here is the component I want to show my data:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getRulesAction} from '../actions/ruleActions';

class Rules extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getRulesAction();
    console.log('props from will mount', this.props);
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.props.rules);
    const fetchedRules = this.props.rules.map((rule,i) => {
        return <li key={i}>{rule}</li>
    }
    )

    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Component to get rules from the redux store</h2>
        {fetchedRules}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

Rules.propTypes = {
  getRulesAction: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rules: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  rules: state.rules.allRules
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getRulesAction})(Rules);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is most probably due to the following. When you declare a state, you need to initialize the state props. You do this by passing a default state to the reducer when it runs for the first time. However, your default state is set to en empty object:

```
export default (state = {}, {type, payload})
```

Therefore, when the component renders for the first time, `this.props.rules` is undefined.
To remedy this, you'd want to initialize the state with `initialState`, which would ensure that `this.props.rules` is an array instead.

```
export default (state = initilState, {type, payload})
```

Later, when the action is fired, the result would be pulled from the updated state.